# Store time in variable when page is loaded

Tags: php

Is there a way to store the time when a page is loaded in a variable?

This is what I got:

```
<?php 
$time = time();
echo "Page loaded:"  . time() ?>
```

However this doesn't do what I want, it shows the current time, not the time when the page was loaded.

Any hints on how to do this is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you want the time for when it started to load, or how long took to load?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding somewhere, can you elaborate what you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: If you want to know when the page was loaded then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`. The `time()` function does not return the time when the page was loaded, it returns the current time.

Answer (score 3):

You want `$time`, the variable you created, not `time()`, another call to the time function.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's because you're not echoing the var:

```
echo "Page loaded:"  . $time;
```